# How could I log that a Windows service is terminating because of a system shutdown?

Tags: event-log

I have a diagnostic version of a service that logs as much as possible in the OnStart() and OnStop() methods.

One event that I am unable to capture is when the computer is physically restarted. My logging function usually records its output to a table in a database, but when that is not available it posts to the EventLog.

On a reboot my service neither logs to the table nor to the EventLog.

It makes sense to me that I would not be able to post to the table, since SQL Server is in the process of shutting down, but it also seems that due to a timing issue the EventLog may also be shutting before the service can default to write there.

In the case of a shutdown, MSSQLSERVER reports an information message in the EventLog:

> SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

Is there a way to do something similar for my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the dependencies of your Windows Service to have it require another service. If you specify a dependency on the EventLog service, then Windows will wait until your service is shut down before shutting down the Event Log.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/400/kb400960.html describes how to do it by modifying a few registry keys.

> Navigate to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
>   and locate the service that you need
>   to set a dependency for. Open the
>   'DependOnService' key on the right
>   side. If the selected service does not
>   have a 'DependOnService' key, then
>   create one by right-clicking and
>   selecting New > Multi-String Value. In
>   the value field, enter the names of
>   all services that the current service
>   will depend on. Each service name must
>   be entered properly and on a separate
>   line.

Comment: Thanks David--that was the solution I used. At first I was hoping to set the dependency programmatically, but with possible permissions issues I think the only way to do that reliably is with installer code. I did mitigate the deployment complexity though by creating a .reg file that I could run. So thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an OnShutdown method your can override in your service. It will be called when the machine is shutting down. Write to the event log from that method, then call base.OnShutdown().

Comment: Frode--in my eventual solution I found that it was also helpful to override OnShutdown(), since OnStop() does not seem to get raised on a system shutdown. Thanks as well!

Answer (score 0):

Capture [SystemEvents.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx)

On the OnStart you could capture it and handle

like

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventHandler(this.zomgRebootinglol);
```

Comment: His issue isn't capturing the shutdown event, its that the logger is already gone by the time his service tries to log.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture windows events by using the [SystemEvents-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx).

Also take a look at the [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents_events.aspx).
I think the Event you are looking for is: **SystemEvents::PowerModeChanged Event** and/or **SystemEvents::SessionEnded**

Comment: His issue isn't capturing the shutdown event, its that the logger is already gone by the time his service tries to log.